# is it possible to update complex data type in hive? e.x: map, array, struct

Tags: hive, hiveql

I wonder:
Is it possible to update complex data type in hive? e.x: map, array, struct
Using ACID tables and UPDATE syntax?

e.g. we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE complex_nested_types_update_array_map (
person_id int,
person_info MAP <STRING, ARRAY <STRING>>)
CLUSTERED BY (person_id) INTO 2 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true");
```

and insert data:

```
insert into table complex_nested_types_update_array_map 
SELECT 1, map('John', array("+44801123311", "+120342234", "+230342234", "+3303422434"));
insert into table complex_nested_types_update_array_map 
SELECT 2, map('Tomas', array("+380342234", "+230342234", "+230342234", "+530342234"));
```

So we have our data in table:

```
select * from complex_nested_types_update_array_map order by person_id;

1   {"John":["+44801123311","+120342234","+230342234","+3303422434"]}
2   {"Tomas":["+380342234","+230342234","+230342234","+530342234"]}
```

Is it possible to update a specific array element without overwriting whole row?

e.g:

```
UPDATE complex_nested_types_update_array_map SET
person_info = map('AAron', array("edited", "edited", "+230342234", "+3303422434"))
WHERE person_id = 2;
```

Updated data:

```
select * from complex_nested_types_update_array_map order by person_id;

1   {"John":["+44801123311","+120342234","+230342234","+3303422434"]}
2   {"AAron":["edited","edited","+230342234","+3303422434"]}
```

But can we update only [2], or only [3] element of array?

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert overwrite` option.

```
insert overwrite table complex_nested_types_update_array_map 
select person_id,map('AAron', array("edited", "edited", "+230342234", "+3303422434")) as person_info
from complex_nested_types_update_array_map 
WHERE person_id = 2
union all
select person_id,person_info
from complex_nested_types_update_array_map 
where person_id<>2
```